# How to Send Claims in Url as well as body in a AAD B2C Custom Policy REST API Call

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In the AAD B2C Custom Policy, I have the following technical profile for REST API Call

```
   <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-AddUserToGroup">
      <DisplayName>Add user to group using Graph API</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://bfc8-77-252-160-45.ngrok-free.app/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members/$ref</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">graphUserUri</Item> 
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
        <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>  
        <Item Key="ClaimResolverUrlFormatting">true</Item>
        <Item Key="DebugMode">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>  
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="REST-AddUserToGroup-UserUri"/>  
      </InputClaimsTransformations> 
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groupId" /> 
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="graphUserUri" /> 
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" /> 
      </InputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

I want to send claim "graphUserUri" in the POST Request Body whereas Claim "groupId" in Url. I can set Metadata "SendClaimIn" as either body or URL but not both. As I set "SendClaimIn" to Body, it sends grapUserUri in the body correctly but does not set groupId in Url.

I wanted to know If there is a way to send a few claims in Body and others in Url.

Comment: You will have to call a proxy API to do this.

Comment: @rbrayb I am already doing it by creating an Azure Function, implementing a graph API call, and then calling that Azure function from Custom Policy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible, following the docs [RESTful technical profile Metadada](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#metadata) you can send data by body or ulr, but not both.